# unexpected behaviour of ruby threading code snippet

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I am trying to learn threading in ruby, i am executing following code:

```
Thread.abort_on_exception = true

threads = 5.times.map do |i|
    Thread.new(i) do |j|
        raise "Boom!" if j == 1
        print "#{j}\n"
    end
end

i=0
loop do
    i+=1
    puts "Waiting!!" if i == 10000
    break if i == 10**4
end

threads.each do |th|
    begin
        th.join
    rescue RuntimeError => e
        puts e
    end
end

puts "Done!!"
```

Sometimes it run perfectly without exception and shows output like:

```
Waiting!!
0
2
3
4
Boom!
Boom!
Done!!
```

and sometimes it quits with exception and shows output like:

```
0
2
3
4
threading.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <main>': Boom! (RuntimeError)
```

Now my questions are:

1. Why? it quits with RuntimeError while i have already rescued it.
2. How could there be two Boom! in output.

Development environment:

- Windows 7 (x64)
- Ruby 2.1.5

Answer (score 1):

The exception is happening in a thread *before* the main thread has reached the block with the `Thread#join` call; specifically, within your loop. The problem is that, with exceptions bubbling up to the main thread, it can literally happen on any line of code; thus, you need to encapsulate error handling within a thread as well. Perhaps it can *return* an error value, but exceptions are fundamentally broken when using this concurrency model.

(To prove this to yourself, try setting `$DEBUG = true` at the top of your file; this will show you where the exceptions really occur.)

Comment: yes i agree but why is it printing Boom! 2 times, while condition could be true only once.

Comment: Both of the "boom" outputs come from the line in the `rescue` block. I'm not sure why, but my hunch is that an exception is raised on both threads, so you get two exceptions being handled (one for the main thread and one for the child thread). This is broken horribly, of course.